# how to pass an object in django?

Tags: python, django

Hello guys i need a bit a help i just started learning Django for 1 month and i am a bit confused how to passing and object through Django? i try the urls thing but it only returned a string base on the type of variable it passing. can anyone give me a tips? how to do this? thanks

here is my code i try to passing the api object to the other function in my view

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib import messages
import routeros_api

def mikrotikapi(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        iprouter = request.POST['iprouter']
        try:
            con = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool(host=iprouter,username=username,password=password,plaintext_login=True)
            api = con.get_api()
            return redirect("dashboard/{}".format(api))
        except:
            messages.info(request,"gak bisa login mas")
            return redirect("mikrotiklogin")
    else:
            return render(request,"loginmikro.html")

def dashboard(request,api):
    resource_log = api.get_resource("log")
    content_log = api.get()
    resource_user = api.get_resource("/ip/hotspot/user")
    content_user  = resource_user.get()
    all_user = len(content_user)
    total_user = 0
    if all_user <= 0:
        total_user = 0
    else:
        total_user = all_user

    return render(request,"dashboard.html")
```

here is my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("dashboard/<api>",views.dashboard,name="dashboard"),
]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass a Python object from `mikrotikapi` to `dashboard ` via a redirect which is not possible. You can only pass a valid URI string. You might benefit from taking the Django tutorial before you continue. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0):

There is a third parameter in render which is used to pass data for templates.

Comment: the thing is i want to send the data (api) to my other view function that is dashboard ()

Answer (score 0):

"Passing an object" doesn't make sense in the context of a web framework. As you wrote your views, you want to register an "api" instance from mikrotikapi view nad retrieve it from your dashboard to use it. Unfortunately, you cannot pass an object instance from one page to another only by adding this object to the URL of the dashboard.

This is a limitation of HTTP protocol, not Django by itself. And this is a common problem that can have many solutions depending on your context.
In general, sharing a full python object instance between pages is not possible without using external tools.

Can you serialize your api instance (transforming the object into a string represention that can be used later to deserialize it ? Then you can store the serialized version of your object into a session and retrieve it in the other view.

Is there a unique ID associated with your object ? Then you can pass this ID from a view to another by setting it in the URL of the second page (or a query param).

Take the time to understand how HTTP protocol works, and how all web frameworks work around this, to understand what you can do waht you cannot.